# Axler exercise 2.B.7

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

> Prove or gibe a counterexample: If $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4$ is a basis of $V$ and $U$ is a subspace of $V$ such that $v_1, v_2 \in U$ and $v_3 \not \in U$ and $v_4 \not \in U$, then $v_1, v_2$ is a basis of $U$.

It turns out that there is a counterexample, but I'm trying to figure out how to figure out a-priori whether a statement like this is true. The first thing I always try to do is prove it and see if I run into a problem. Provided that there are edge cases where my proof fails, I'll use them to try to find a counterexample. However, I managed to write down a proof of this and couldn't find any holes in it, though there surely is one.

> Let $u \in U \subset V$, so there exist $a_1, \ldots, a_4 \in F$ such that
> $$u = a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_4 v_4,$$
> since $v_1, \ldots, v_4$ is a basis of $V$ and $u \in V$ .But $u - (a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2) \in U$ since $v_1, v_2 \in U$, which would imply that $a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 \in U$. Since $v_3, v_4 \not \in U$, this implies that $a_3 v_3 + a_3 v_4 = 0$. That is, $u = a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2$, so $v_1$ and $v_2$ span $U$. Furthermore, if there exist coefficients $a_1, \ldots, a_4$ such that
> $$a_1 v_1 + \ldots + a_4 v_4 = 0,$$
> then $a_1 = a_2 = a_3 = a_4 = 0$ by linear independence, so $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. So $v_1, v_2$ is a basis for $U$.

The only step of this that I can see may be a leap of logic is the conclusion "so $a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 = 0$. This seems like a jump, but I can't find another case where $a_3 v_3 + a_4 v_4 \in U$ but $v_3, v_4$ are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right.  Let $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ be the standard basis.  Let $U$ have $\{v_1, v_2, v_3 + v_4\}$ for a basis. Then $v_3$ is not in $U$, and $v_4$ is not in $U$. But the subspace is 3 dimensional, not 2.

Comment: This makes much more sense, but how do you know that $v_3 + v_4$ is a basis vector for $U$?

Comment: You can't prove it impossible because it is true in some cases and not others. You have to add some sort of assumption to draw the conclusion either way. So I created an example (made an assumption) to show that your proof had a hole in it where you suspected.

Comment: So in other words, it is not necessarily true that $a_3 v_4 + a_4 v_4 = 0$, and this is one way in which the claim fails. That makes sense. Thank you again.